# Proving that a set is a basis for the neighborhoods

Tags: general-topology

> Take $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology $\mathcal{T}$.
>
> Let $A = \{n^{-1}\mid n \in \mathbb{N}\}$.
>
> Define the topology $\mathcal{S}$ as the topology generated by
>   $\mathcal{T} \cup \{\mathbb{R}\setminus A\}$.
>
> Define $\mathcal{B}(x)$ as the set $\{]x - \epsilon,x + \epsilon[:
>  \epsilon >0\}$ if $x\neq 0$ and as the set
>    $\{]-\epsilon,\epsilon[\setminus A : \epsilon > 0\}$
>
> Prove that this is a basis for the neighborhoods on the topological
>   space $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{S})$.

**My attempt:**

I was able to prove that $\mathcal{B}(x)$ is contained in the neighborhoods of the point $x$, but I was not able to formally show that we can write $B \subset V$ for all neighborhoods $V$ of $x$ and for some $B \in \mathcal{B}(x)$. This seems tedious, and I wonder how I can write it neatly.

Comment: I assume $X=\Bbb R$ (as sets)? But the definition of the "balls" makes no sense to me, is there maybe one $\mathcal{B}_\epsilon(x)$ for each $\epsilon$? I mean $\mathcal{B}_\epsilon(x) := ]x-\epsilon, x+\epsilon[$ resp. $\mathcal{B}_\epsilon(0) := ]-\epsilon,\epsilon]\setminus A$ -- that would sound reasonable to me.

Comment: For the first question, yes. For the second question, for every x we define a set of neighborhoods of $x$ and we have to show that this is a basis for all neighborhoods of x

Comment: Oh, I see. Sorry, I thought of the individual open balls, but it makes perfect sense as you wrote it.

Comment: For more context, this topology should provide an example of a space where the implication "Hausdorff $\implies$ regular" fails.

Comment: This is called the $\mathbb{R}_K$ topology in Munkres.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we have $\mathcal{S}' = \mathcal{T} \cup \{(X\setminus A)\}$ as a subbase (a generating set), then we have a base $\mathcal{B}$ consisting of all finite intersections from $\mathcal{S}'$. Such a finite intersection is always of the form $O$ where $O \in \mathcal{T}$ (when the set $X\setminus A$ is not part of the intersection), as then all sets from the intersection come from $\mathcal{T}$, which is closed under finite intersections, or of the form $O \setminus A$, with $O \in \mathcal{T}$ (which includes $X\setminus O$ itself).

So $\mathcal{B} = \mathcal{T} \cup \{O \setminus A: O \in \mathcal{T}\}$ forms a base for the topology $\mathcal{S}$.

> (1) For every set $B \in \mathcal{B}$ and every $x \in B$ we can find a $B' \in \mathcal{B}(x)$ such that $x \in B' \subseteq B$,

and as also $\cup_{x \in X} \mathcal{B}(x) \subseteq \mathcal{S}$ we have that the collection you gave is a family of local bases for $\mathcal{S}$.

Statement (1) can be shown as follows: suppose $x \in B$ and $B$ is of the first form, i.e. a member of $\mathcal{T}$. Then by properties of the usual topology we have some $\varepsilon >0$ such that $(x-\varepsilon, x+\varepsilon) \subseteq B$, and so we have our member $B' \in \mathcal{B}(x)$ for $x \neq 0$ and for $x \neq 0$ we can take the even smaller set $(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)\setminus A \in \mathcal{B}(0)$. If $B$ is of the second form, so $B=O \setminus A$ where $O$ open in $\mathcal{T}$ then if $x=0$ is in $B=O\setminus A$ we can find $\varepsilon>0$ such that $(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon) \subseteq O$ and then $\mathcal{B}(0) \ni (-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)\setminus A  \subseteq B$, as required. And if $x \neq 0$ lies in $B$, then $C=A \cup\{0\}$ is closed in $\mathcal{T}$ and $x \in O \setminus C  = O \cap (X\setminus C)$, which is an open set of $\mathcal{T}$, so we have $\varepsilon >0$ again with $\mathcal{B}(x) \ni (x-\varepsilon, x+\varepsilon) \subseteq O \setminus C \subset B$, as required.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I figured it out by handling more cases, but your answer looks shorter. Will have a look at it!

Comment: I figured my answer was essentially the same as yours, but I considered the case that $X\setminus A$ could be a finite intersection apart, which you didn't. Thanks for confirming my thought process, and also thanks for all the other questions you help me with.

Comment: @Math_QED glad to be able to help!